# How to allow JQuery event handler to access variables in module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var MODULE = (function() {
    var app = {
        hi: "hi mom", // I can't access this. Oh' what do I do?
        onSubmitClick: function() {
            $('button').click(function() {
                console.log(hi); // I want to access the above hi variable..eeek!
            })
        },
        run: function() {
            this.onSubmitClick()
        }
    }
    return app
}());

var newApp = MODULE;
newApp.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hi` is not a variable, it is a property of the object `app`

```
var MODULE = (function () {

    var app = {
        hi: "hi mom",
        onSubmitClick: function () {
            $('button').click(function () {
                console.log(app.hi); //use the app object and access the property
            })
        },
        run: function () {
            this.onSubmitClick()
        }
    }
    return app
}());


var newApp = MODULE;
newApp.run();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sVBDH/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this also.

```
var app = {
        hi: "hi mom",
        onSubmitClick: function (cthis) {
            $('button').click(function () {
                alert(cthis.hi); //use the app object and access the property
            })
        },
        run: function () {

            this.onSubmitClick(this);
            //-------------------^ this is referring app
        }
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sVBDH/2/)